# How do I remove the word "Attribute" from intellisense / autocomplete options in my custom class?

Tags: c#, autocomplete, attributes, intellisense

I'd like my custom attributes to not show the word Attribute, just like 'builtin' attributes.

"TooltipAttribute" is a class. When I type "[tool", I only have the option to complete it to "[Tooltip" (tooltipx in the image is irrelevant).

I want my class to behave the same way, but when I type "[dispif", I only have the option to complete it to "[DisplayIfAttribute". I've never used attributes before. If I manually correct the code to read "[DisplayIf(whatever)]", it works correctly; I just want the autocomplete option to not include "attribute".

I'm using the version of Monodevelop that comes with Unity 4.something.

This image shows my autocomplete giving me the options:
[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pca109hili5edjm/help%20attribute.png]

Comment: You might look at the source for `ToolTipAttribute` and see if there's an attribute applied to it that gives a short name or something? It does seem like a monodevelop-specific thing.

Comment: `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]` This comment system is defeating me. :)  That is the only thing I can see in Tooltip besides class/field declarations, and adding that to mine doesn't do anything (surprise). I think it may be monodevelop-specific - they do have lots of formatting oddities - i'll see if I can find something in whatever their support is.

Comment: monodev strikse (out) again -- http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/monodevelops-autocomplete-for-attirbutes-is-dumb-what-do-you-do.167047/

Comment: Well, hey ... it's open source. You can go change the IDE yourself if you like! (No, I don't honestly believe that's a reasonable solution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your class name ends with Attribute, and the class inherits from System.Attribute, you will see the "shortened" name in intellisense when type the attribute into brackets `[]`.

```
public class TestAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

On the other hand, you'll see the full name if you're referencing it in other code.

Comment: But I am seeing "DisplayIfAttribute" when typing it into brackets. Inheriting directly from Attribute does not change that behavior. It's possible this is Monodevelop-specific malarkey.